# How to call .post() in a given time interval?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I would like to update some `<div>` in a given time interval.
Let say every 3 seconds call `mypost()` function.

How to do that in jquery?

Thanks
Arman.

Comment: You mean *after* some time or *during* some time or *every* X (timeunit) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in jquery that allows you to do this because there's the native javascript [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) function:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // this will be invoked on every 5s
    $.post(...);
}, 5000);
```

If you want to invoke it only once:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    // this will be invoked after 5s only once
    $.post(...);
}, 5000);
```